# Particle to express pride or accomplishment / 自豪感的助词

Tags: particles

What is the way to emphasize personal pride or accomplishment in Chinese without sounding arrogant -- is there are a particle for this to put at the end of the sentence? For example:

> I just had a child!
>
> I just bought a house!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 啦 with the exclamation mark at the end of a sentence.

For instance:

- I just had a child!

  > 我有孩子啦！

  or

  > 我的孩子出生啦！
- I just bought a house!

  > 我买房子啦！

Answer (score 2):

我有孩子啦!!!

我当爹啦~~~

Yeah, 我赢啦.

我买房子啦,hoho.

Sometimes honorific express pride and your humor in modern usage.

> I just bought a house!

**不才, 小可新购入一座房子, 惭愧, 惭愧.**

不才 = I am not clever,

小可 = I

惭愧 = ashamed, but in today, it just show your pride, and humor

> I just bought a house!

**在下家中新添人口. (do not add 惭愧 this case, otherwise ...)**

在下 = I

新添人口 = 添丁 = you have a baby

我刚买一台新单反, 惭愧,惭愧.

我刚中了一等奖, 惭愧, 惭愧.